# Asynchronous bulk uploads of docs and email notification in spring boot

Tags: asynchronous, notifications, upload

I need to create a rest API for bulk uploads of documents and then send the email notification of successful uploads. How can I achieve these two task first uploads and then emails both  asynchronously as bulk uploads is a long running process.

Can we do this via completable future or any better approach if someone can suggest?